# Symfony2 server 500 error on live site

Tags: php, git, apache, .htaccess, symfony

I have a project works fine locally on ubuntu server and local host.

I've git cloned the project from bitbucket to my centos apache2 server, which is the live hosted server, it created a folder which the git repository was named on bit bucket, but should still be ok I think, unless anyone knows if symfony2 requires it to be installed on the httpdocs folder directly to work? I did my git clone in /var/www/vhosts/namesite/httpdocs and it created in the project in /var/www/vhost/namesite/httpdocs/myprojectfolder

I get 500 internal server errors when trying to view http://sitename/myprojectfolder/web/app_dev.php , when I look at dev.log folder get this

```
     "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTer  minate". []$   [2015-06-27 18:34:41] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate"         to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onTerminate".
```

Any ideas I don't need .htaccess as this stage do I ?

Comment: the server website works if I access the domain and refers to a index.html file, this is frustrating, I always seem to have to spend ages deploy symfony

Answer (score 0):

ha ha - just thought, I'd check my server settings to compare a working site in symfony.  It turns out that plesk installs sites with 'fast cgi' settings.  I changed it to run as 'apache_module' and it works, it now works.  Time for a drink!